# How to get iPad PRO simulator on Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, xcode7

In Xcode 7.0.1 there's an iPad Air 2 and an iPad Retina simulators. Is iPad Retina the iPad Pro? If not, how do I get iPad Pro simulator for Xcode 7.0.1.

(I know Xcode 7.1 has iPad Pro simulators also but for some reason I can't download an upgrade to Xcode 7.1 from the App store, it always just stops downloading and installing without giving me any error messages. I also tried downloading it from developers downloads page and that did't work either. Maybe a download issue with Xcode 7.1.)

Comment: ipad retina is not ipad pro. You can download the ipad pro from xcode 7.1 !!!

Answer (score 1):

iPad pro simulator is not available for xcode 7.0.1 you will have to upgrade to 7.1 to use it and iPad Retina is not iPad Pro in xcode 7.0.1, iPad Retina is 9.7 inch device

Comment: But I literally can't upgrade to Xcode 7.1 App Store won't upgrade it just stops mid download and gives me no errors. Same thing happens when I tried upgrading to Xcode 7.1 on developer downloads page.

Comment: it is difficult to help with that information, you can start another question as this discusion is off the topic of current question